# Can I index the existence of a value in a column (whether it is null or not)?

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing

I have a varchar(999) column that I want to select only when it is not NULL.

Is there an efficient way to check whether a row has NULL value or not without indexing all the possible values for this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `WHERE col IS NOT NULL` may use the NULL bitmap but it's a clustered index scan.

Or you just index the column and take the hit. Or use an indexed view with the IS NOT NULL filter.

Unfortunately, this isn't resolved elegantly until "[filtered indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)" SQL Server 2008